# How to callback function in Widget Build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function `_tables()` that is called once when building widgets. I need to call it again when onTap event. I tried a common call but nothing happens. How to re-call a function?
Some code:

```
class DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
....
    _tables() {
    if (selectedValue == "a") {
      return DataA();
    }
    if (selectedValue == "b") {
      return DataB();
    }
    if (selectedValue == "c") {
      return DataC();
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(...
body: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _tables(),
         ... new Stack(children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedContainer(...),
                      InkWell(onTap: () => setState(
                      () {
                        _tables();
                      },
                    ),)])...}
```

Comment: the widget will be the same if you don't change the `selectedValue` value

Comment: I know, but i need reinitialize widget in onTap event

Comment: you are calling `_tables` again and it's working , why do you need?

Comment: Because DataA()..DataC() widgets has conditions, and if I reinitialize this widget conditions will changed and I need it.

Comment: do this :  
setState(
                      () {  selectedValue = "b"; 
                        _tables();
                      },
                    )       and you will see how the widget changes

Comment: @diegoveloper You misunderstood the problem. See my answer in case you are still wondering.

Comment: Well that's a weird problem :) I don't know why he wants to do that but thats ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force a widget to rebuild, you have to either change its `runtimeType` or `key` (see [`Widget.canUpdate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/canUpdate.html)).

In your case, you can make use of this fact by supplying a key to your widgets and updating that in your `onTap`:

```dart
class DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
//  ...

  String selectedValue;

  Key tableKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tableKey = UniqueKey();
  }

  Widget _tables() {
    if (selectedValue == "a") {
      return DataA(
        key: tableKey,
      );
    }
    if (selectedValue == "b") {
      return DataB(
        key: tableKey,
      );
    }
    if (selectedValue == "c") {
      return DataC(
        key: tableKey,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _tables(),
          Stack(children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
//          ...
                ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                tableKey = UniqueKey();
              }),
            )
          ]),
//          ...
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, you need to define an initial key in `initState` and then you can update that key in your `onTap`. See [`UniqueKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html) to learn more.

**Make sure** that your `Data{A/B/C}` widgets have a named parameter `key` that you pass to the super constructor:

```dart
class DataA extends StatelessWidget {

  const DataA({
    Key key,
//    ...
  }) : super(key: key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code according to yours, but the key parameter in classes DataA(key: tableKey,)...DataB(..) is underlined by red and writes an error: "The named parameter key isn't defined".

Comment: @WhyTooHard I mentioned this in my answer. You need to add a `key` parameter to your data widgets.